# Sequel: DB2 Adapter Not Found

Tags: ruby, db2, sequel

Okay, I've been trying to connect to a DB2 Database. I've been trying to use Sequel, in the hope of building some POROs for accessing data in my DB2 Database.

So after installing Sequel, I've been trying to do the following in irb

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.connect('db2://myuser:mypass@myhost.com:10000/mydatabase')
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- db2/db2cli
```

Looking at the sequel source for the DB2 Adapter inside sequel, this is generating from this require statement

```
require 'db2/db2cli'
```

So I installed every gem I thought It could be trying to require: db2, ibm_db and dbi. I've also downloaded the CLI and put it in my system path and downloaded an DB2 Express C. No matter what I try, I can't get past this require statment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to install `ibm_db` and use `ibmdb://...` instead of `db2://...`.  `db2://...` is for the old `db2/db2cli` driver which is not available in gem form (you can get it at http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/8264/ruby-db2-0.4.4.tar.gz).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know!